# Avoid the object/array check and treat the return value the same way with JavaScript spread operator?

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to implement a function (a template-helper function) which provides a simple merge-like functionality for both arrays and objects. The two functions are basically looks identical:

```javascript
const mergeArrays = (first, ...rest) =>
  rest.reduce((acc, curr) => ([ ...acc, ...curr]), first);

const mergeObjects = (first, ...rest) =>
  rest.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), first);
```

One could do a **type check and a local variable** to write a single function like this:

```javascript
const mergeArraysOrObjects1 = (first, ...rest) => {
  let reducer = null;
  if ('object' === typeof first && null !== first) {
    reducer = (acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, ...curr });
  }
  if (Array.isArray(first)) {
    reducer = (acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr];
  }

  if (!reducer) {
    throw new Error('The "merge" filter only works with arrays and hashes.');
  }

  return rest.reduce(reducer, first);
}
```

... but it seems so ugly to me. Another possibility is a **type check and inline conditional**:

```javascript
const mergeArraysOrObjects2 = (first, ...rest) => {
  if ('object' !== typeof first || null === first) {
    throw new Error('The "merge" filter only works with arrays and hashes.');
  }

  return rest.reduce(
    (acc, curr) => Array.isArray(acc) ? [...acc, ...curr] : {...acc, ...curr},
    first
  );
}
```

I'm still learning JavaScript so I'm guessing if there is a more elegant and concise way to treat the return value the same way.

Answer (score 1):

### `Object.assign` && `Array.flat`

By the first example which does not have any type checking makes the throwing of errors in the second two examples look superfluous, a little over kill.

As the function `Array.isArray` is the more concise statement over the always ugly object test `typeof obj === "Object && obj !== null` you can use a simple ternary to call the correct function

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) rather than the long and slow object by object reduce method to merge objects.

And for the array `Array.push`, then [Array.flat(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) depth of 1 for the arrays. To ensure you do not effect the input array `first` you would also need to copy it to a new array

#### Examples.

```
const merge = (first, ...rest) => {
    const arrays = (arr) => (arr.push(...rest), arr.flat(1));
    const objects = () => Object.assign({}, first,  ...rest);        
    return Array.isArray(first) ? arrays([[...first]]) : objects();
}
```

Or a shortened form

```
const merge = (first, ...rest) => {
    return Array.isArray(first) ? 
         (first = [[...first]], first.push(...rest), first.flat(1)) : 
         Object.assign({}, first,  ...rest);
}
```

### Update

Fixed bug as pointed out in comments.

From the same comment by *ScottyJamison* in which is presented an even better solution, using the rest operator on all the arguments resulting in...

```
const merge = (...items) => Array.isArray(items[0]) ? 
    items.flat(1) : 
    Object.assign({}, ...items);
```

or

```
const merge = (...items) => Array.isArray(items[0]) ? items.flat(1) : Object.assign({}, ...items);
```

Comment: Your example is broken - if the first array has subarrays, they would get flattened, which is different from the O.P.'s implementation. Why not just do to this? `const merge = (...items) => Array.isArray(items[0]) ? items.flat(1) : Object.assign({}, ...items);`

Comment: @ScottyJamison Yes thank you very much for pointing that out. Will fix it. :)